# styling a menu inside a div

Tags: html, css

How can I access the ul and the li menu inside the div in CSS?

```
<section id="main">
            <div id="=cont">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="about.html"> Our Hitory </a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="index.html"> The Foundation </a></li>
                            <li><a href="about.html"> Our Founders </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="about.html"> Our Company </a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="index.html"> Our Business Practices </a></li>
                            <li><a href="about.html"> Our Brokers </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

               </ul>
           </div>
```

I've tried so many combinations in css but can't seem to be able to access that menu and style it.

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: `div#cont > ul li` You should consider reading about CSS though, you'll understand what you have to do.

Comment: div#cont > ul li{
} Isnt working though.

Comment: I wanna style both the inner and outer uls and lis.

Comment: Drop the equal sign before the ID name. id="cont" not id="=cont"

Comment: Oh dammit. Thanks a lot Doug. I've been staring at this and didnt really catch this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mistake in `<div id="=cont">` change it to `<div id="cont">` like this

```css
#cont > ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}

#cont > ul li{
 padding: 10px;
 background: green;
}

#cont >ul li ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}

#cont >ul li ul li{
  padding: 10px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
    
    
    <section id="main">
                <div id="cont">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="about.html"> Our Hitory </a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="index.html"> The Foundation </a></li>
                                <li><a href="about.html"> Our Founders </a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="about.html"> Our Company </a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="index.html"> Our Business Practices </a></li>
                                <li><a href="about.html"> Our Brokers </a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
    
                   </ul>
               </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is an example of stylization
Taken from: http://www.java2s.com/Code/HTMLCSS/Tags/SettingstyleforULinsideaDIV.htm

```css
#footer ul {
  width: 1000px;
  text-align: center;
}
#footer li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 44px;
}
#footer li a {
  color: #574621;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
#footer li a:visited {
  text-decoration: none
}
#footer li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline
}
```

```html
?<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US"
  xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
<title></title>
<style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="footer">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>|</li>
      <li><a href="#">About our Hotel</a>|</li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a>|</li>
      <li><a href="#">Photogallery</a>|</li>
      <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a>|</li>
      <li><a href="#">Locations</a>|</li>
      <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>  
  
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To speak to a Tag you can use in the CSS Sheet things like

Example 1:

```
  .id ul li {
     your Css Code
  }
  /* in your case  */
  .cont {
    position: ...;
  }

  /* Or for deeper Tags  
  * for example:
  */

 .cont ul li a {
     position: ...;
 }
```

or but that is a bad Programmingstyle

Example 2:

```
 <li style="color:green"><a href="about.html"> Our Hitory </a>
```

there is also a third option to put css Code like in example 1 in a styletag in the head tag

Example 3:

```
 <head> 
 <style>
 <!-- Code from Example 1 -->
 </style>
 </head>
```

Hope i can help you!

If you have any Questions left just ask.

Good Luck